# Trouble with the Erdõs-Gallai Theorem

Tags: graph-theory

I have been reading the book Graph Theory by Ronald Gould. When he discusses the degree sequences, he gives an example of how to apply the Erdõs-Gallai theorem to check if a degree sequence can represent a graph or not. I didn't understand the notation(I mean, the results didn't match with other examples that I have seen), so I would like to ask for some help, if possible. Maybe a step-by-step calculation for each k of the example could solve this question.

[image: Example of Erdõs-Gallai Theorem from Graph Theory book by Ronald Gould]

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to check is that the sum of the sequence $5,5,5,5,2,2,2$ is even. The sum is 26, so this is true.

For any $k$ you now have to check that the sum of the first $k$ elements is less than $k(k-1)$ plus the sum of the remaining elements, but each one capped at $k.$

So, for $k=1$ you are checking $5 \le 1 \cdot 0 + (1+1+1+1+1+1),$ which is true (since $5\le 6$).

For $k=2$ you are checking $5 + 5 \le 2\cdot 1 + (2+2+2+2+2),$ which is true (since $10\le 12$).

For $k=3$ you are checking $5 + 5 + 5 \le 3\cdot 2 + (3+2+2+2),$ which is true (since $15\le 15$).

For $k=4$ you are checking $5 + 5 + 5 + 5 \le 4\cdot 3 + (2+2+2),$ which is **not** true (since $20\not\le 18$).

Thus, the sequence $5,5,5,5,2,2,2$ is not graphical according to the Erdős–Gallai theorem, in other words, no graph has this sequence as a degree sequence.

---

It is also instructive to see why this is so. The 4 vertices of degree 5 (call them $U$) have at most $4 \cdot 3 / 2 = 6$ edges among themselves, which absorb $4\cdot 3 = 12$ of the degrees. As the degree sum of $U$ is 20, there must be at least $20-12=8$ edges going from one of $U$ to the remaining 3 vertices $V-U.$ But the degree sum of $V-U$ is only 6, which is not sufficient.

From this, it is also clear why we have to cap the degrees of $V-U$ by $|U|.$

Answer (score -1):

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
Erdös-Gallai\ Theorem\ ( Example)\\
\\
The\ first\ condition\ we\ should\ verify\ is\ if\ the\ sum\ of\ the\ degrees\ is\ even.\\
1) \ \sum _{i=1}^{p} Di\ =\ Even\\
\\
If\ the\ above\ condition\ is\ true,\ we\ can\ continue\ to\ the\ following\ condition.\\
\\
2) \ \sum _{i=1}^{K} d_{i} \ \leqslant \ K( K-1) \ +\ \sum _{i\ =\ K\ +\ 1}^{p} min\{K,\ d_{i}\}\\
\\
If\ we\ have\ the\ sequence\ S:\ 2,\ 2,2\ for\ example,\ we\ apply\ the\ above\ formula\ for\ each\ term\ of\ the\\
sequence.\ So,\ for\ the\ first\ term,\ or\ K\ =\ 1,\ we\ have:\\
\\
\sum _{i=1}^{K} d_{i} \ \Longrightarrow \ \sum _{i=1}^{1} 2\ =\ 2\\
\\
Then,\ we\ substitute\ K( K-1) \ for\ the\ number\ 1,\ which\ results\ in\ 1( 1-1) \ =\ 0.\\
\\
Finally,\ the\ last\ part\ we\ gonna\ sum\ the\ minimum\ of\ the\ terms\ starting\ in\ index\ k\ +\ 1\ until\ the\\
last\ term.\ In\ this\ example,\ we\ have:\\
\\
\sum _{i\ =\ 2}^{2} min\{1,\ 2\} \ \rightarrow \ min\{1,2\} \ +\ min\{1,2\} \ \rightarrow \ 1\ +\ 1\ =\ 2\\
\\
The\ final\ result\ is:\ 2\ +\ 0\ =\ 2\\
\\
Finally\ we\ can\ compare\ the\ results:\ 2\leqslant 2\ \rightarrow \ This\ is\ true,\ so\ we\ can\ continue\ the\ process.\\
\\
For\ K=2:\\
\sum _{i=1}^{K} d_{i} \ \Longrightarrow \ \sum _{i=1}^{2} 2\ +\ 2\ =\ 4\\
\\
K( K-1) \ \rightarrow \ 2( 2-1) \ =\ 2\\
\\
\sum _{i\ =\ 3}^{2} min\{2,\ 2\} \ \rightarrow \ min\{2,2\} \ =\ 2\\
\\
The\ final\ result\ is:\ 2\ +\ 2\ =\ 4\\
\\
Finally\ we\ can\ compare\ the\ results:\ 4\leqslant 4\ \rightarrow \ This\ is\ true,\ so\ we\ can\ continue\ the\ process.\\
\\
For\ K\ =\ 3:\\
\sum _{i=1}^{K} d_{i} \ \Longrightarrow \ \sum _{i=1}^{3} 2\ +\ 2\ +\ 2=6\\
\\
K( K-1) \ \rightarrow \ 3( 3-1) \ =\ 6\\
\\
OBS:\ In\ this\ case,\ we\ only\ have\ 3\ terms\ but\ should\ start\ in\ the\ fourth\ index,\ so\ we\ consider\ as\ 0.\\
\\
\sum _{i\ =\ 4}^{3} min( d_{i} ,\ 3) \ \rightarrow \ min( 0,\ 3) \ =\ 0\\
\\
The\ final\ result\ is:\ 6\ +\ 0\ =\ 6\\
\\
Finally\ we\ can\ compare\ the\ results:\ 6\leqslant 6\ \rightarrow \ This\ is\ true,\ so\ we\ can\ conclude\ that\ the\ sequence\ \\
S\ =\ \{2,2,2\} \ can\ represent\ a\ graph,\ and\ in\ fact\ we\ can\ draw\ the\ following\ graph:
\end{array}$

[Graph generated by the degree sequence S={2,2,2}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNoP1.png)

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
Let's\ take\ the\ sequence\ S:\ 5,5,5,5,2,2,2\ as\ another\ example\ and\ check\ using\ the\ above\ formulas.\\
\\
For\ the\ first\ condition:\\
( 5\ \times \ 4) \ +\ ( 2\ \times \ 3) \ =\ 26,\ which\ is\ even,\ so\ we\ can\ continue.\\
\\
For\ the\ second\ condition:\\
\\
I) \ For\ K\ =\ 1\\
\\
First\ part:\ \\
\sum _{i=1}^{1} d_{i} \ =\ 5\ \Rightarrow \ \sum _{i=1}^{K} d_{i}\\
\\
Second\ part:\\
\ 1( 1-1) \ =\ 1( 0) \ =\ 0\ ( As\ the\ result\ is\ 0,\ we\ can\ desconsider) ;\\
\\
\sum _{i\ =\ 2}^{7} min\{1,5\} \Rightarrow \sum _{i\ =\ K\ +\ 1}^{p} min\{K,\ d_{i}\}\rightarrow min\{1,5\} +min\{1,5\} +min\{1,5\} +min\{1,2\} +\\
min\{1,2\} +min\{1,2\}\} \ \rightarrow \ 1\ +\ 1\ +\ 1\ +\ 1\ +\ 1\ +\ 1=\ 6\\
\\
Observation:\ As\ indicated\ in\ the\ formula,\ we\ should\ begin\ our\ sum\ with\ the\ term\ K\ +\ 1,\ \\
so\ in\ our\ case\ \ we\ are\ going\ to\ start\ the\ sum\ within\ the\ second\ term\ of\ the\ sequence,highlighted\ \\
in\ red:\\
S:\ 5, 5 ,5,5,2,2,2.\ \\
\\
Now\ we\ can\ compare\ both\ results:\ 5\ \leqslant \ 6\ \rightarrow \ True,\ so\ we\ go\ to\ the\ next\ term\ of\ the\ sequence\ \\
and\ repeat\ the\ process.\\
\\
II) \ For\ K\ =\ 2\\
\\
First\ part:\\
\sum _{i=1}^{2} d_{i} \ =\ 5\ +5\ =\ 10\ \Rightarrow \ \sum _{i=1}^{K} d_{i}\\
\\
Second\ part:\\
\ 2( 2-1) \ =\ 2( 1) \ =\ 2\ ( After\ the\ sum,\ we\ gonna\ add\ two\ to\ the\ result) .\\
\\
We\ gonna\ start\ the\ sum\ within\ the\ third\ term\ of\ the\ sequence,\ highlighted\ in\ red:\\
S:\ 5,5, 5 ,5,2,2,2.\ \\
\\
\sum _{i\ =\ 3}^{7} min\{2,5\} \Rightarrow \sum _{i\ =\ K\ +\ 1}^{p} min\{K,\ d_{i}\}\rightarrow min\{2,5\} +min\{2,5\} +min\{2,2\} +min\{2,2\} +\\
min\{2,2\}\} \ \rightarrow \ 2\ +\ 2\ +\ 2\ +\ 2\ +\ 2=\ 10\\
\\
Now\ we\ add\ the\ number\ 2\ obtained\ previously,\ the\ result\ is\ 12.\\
\\
Finally\ we\ compare\ both\ results:\ 10\ \leqslant \ 12\ \rightarrow \ True,\ so\ we\ continue\ the\ process.\\
\\
III) \ For\ k\ =\ 3\\
\\
First\ part:\\
\sum _{i=1}^{3} d_{i} \ =\ 5\ +5\ +\ 5\ =\ 15\ \Rightarrow \ \sum _{i=1}^{K} d_{i}\\
\\
Second\ part:\\
\ 3( 3-1) \ =\ 3( 2) \ =\ 6\ ( After\ the\ sum,\ we\ gonna\ add\ 6\ to\ the\ result) .\\
\\
We\ gonna\ start\ the\ sum\ within\ the\ fourth\ term\ of\ the\ sequence,\ highlighted\ in\ red:\\
S:\ 5,5,5, 5 ,2,2,2.\ \\
\\
\sum _{i\ =\ 4}^{7} min\{3,5\} \Rightarrow \sum _{i\ =\ K\ +\ 1}^{p} min\{K,\ d_{i}\}\rightarrow min\{3,5\} +min\{3,2\} +min\{3,2\} +min\{3,2\}\} \ \\
\\
\rightarrow \ 3\ +\ 2\ +\ 2\ +\ 2\ =\ 9\\
\\
Now\ we\ add\ the\ number\ 6\ obtained\ previously,\ the\ result\ is\ 15.\\
\\
Finally\ we\ compare\ both\ results:\ 15\ \leqslant \ 15\ \rightarrow \ True,\ so\ we\ can\ continue\ the\ process.\\
\\
IV) \ For\ K\ =\ 4\\
\\
First\ part:\\
\sum _{i=1}^{4} d_{i} \ =\ 5\ +5\ +\ 5\ +\ 5=\ 20\ \Rightarrow \ \sum _{i=1}^{K} d_{i}\\
\\
Second\ part:\\
\ 4( 4-1) \ =\ 4( 3) \ =\ 12\ ( After\ the\ sum,\ we\ gonna\ add\ 12\ to\ the\ result) .\\
\\
We\ gonna\ start\ the\ sum\ within\ the\ fifth\ term\ of\ the\ sequence,\ highlighted\ in\ red:\\
S:\ 5,5,5,5, 2 ,2,2.\ \\
\\
\sum _{i\ =\ 5}^{7} min\{4,2\} \Rightarrow \sum _{i\ =\ K\ +\ 1}^{p} min\{K,\ d_{i}\}\rightarrow min\{4,2\} +min\{4,2\} +min\{4,2\}\} \ \rightarrow \ 2\ +\ 2\ +\ 2=6\\
\\
Now\ we\ add\ the\ number\ 12\ obtained\ previously,\ the\ result\ is\ 18.\\
\\
Finally\ we\ compare\ both\ results:\ 20\ \leqslant \ 18\ \rightarrow \ False,\ so\ we\ can\ stop\ the\ process\ and\ conclude\\
that\ the\ sequence\ \{5,5,5,5,2,2,2\} \ does\ not\ form\ a\ graph.\\
\end{array}$

Comment: This is hard to read. Why do you write *everything* using MathJax?

Comment: I thought it would be handy and the best way to express the ideas formally, but I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The problem here is not only that the whole huge text is in the form of a single formula, but also that a very simple criterion is turned into a super difficult to understand algorithm.